# WCF Security License Scenario

Tags: c#, wcf, security, service

We are trying to build up the best security scenario for our case.

One company can install our software in multiple computers. One company can buy multiple licenses that can be shared between their employees. Every time one employee wants to use our software, he/she will be able to see a popup screen where all the licenses the company has bought will be shown. Then, if a license is being used, the employee will be able to see who is using it.

1. No password has to be entered in order to see all the company licenses. There is a need to distinguish the licenses a company has bought.
2. When a user wants to use a license (use the application), he will have to enter his own password.

The connection between the WPF Application and the Server will be done using a WCF Service. There must be some kind of a token that will check if the connection to the server is still possible every 5 minutes otherwise the application will close.

What we have thought here is to deploy one certificate for every company. Whenever this company will be authenticated using the certificate, we will be able to show the company licenses whenever the application will be launched.

Then, when a user wants to open the application, he will select one license, and a password box will be prompted. Another authentication will be done using the SQLMembershipProvider.

Would it be possible to be implemented? Please tell us your thought about it.

Comment: All of this is, as a matter of course, possible... but the bigger question is whether or not you _want_ to implement such a system. Consider the case where your license server or a company loses their internet access for a short period of time (say 15 minutes, even). What happens then? There's a lot of other possible scenarios, and that's just the legitimate cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told where server is hosted - on-premise or central location. And what is needed is unnamed licenses to track concurrent users (or concurrent sessions i.e. same user may use application from multiple computers). This is outline of what I would have done for on-premise server:

- For every company, create a license
  file. It could be as simple as an xml
  file containing data such as number
  of licenses, expiry date, company
  identifier (& other information).
  Important thing is to encrypt
  contents using your private key. You should also store hash to check against tampering
- The license file would be given to each company to place on their server at configured location. The license delivery can be manual (email/web download) or automated (provide registration key to download the license)
- Server code will read the license using your public key and apply licensing rules.
- For centrally hosted server, outline will be similar but license store will be in your control and as such there is no need to encrypt that data. However, what is important is to issue each company some identifier token (say digital certificate) so that you can track license against correct company.

User authentication is as such unrelated to this and you can use any authentication scheme that you want. Whenever user is authenticated (say using user-name/password), a license will be marked consumed. For central server (hosted services) model, you can use user authentication to also authenticate company (w/o issuing a separate digital certificate to them).